# How can I use pull-to-refresh functionality in a PhoneGap application without iScroll?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, iscroll, pull-to-refresh

I have a PhoneGap project set up for iPhone, Android and WP8.

To refresh the content of the UIWebView I'd like to offer pull-to-refresh functionality to the user.

Due to other restrictions I can't use a JavaScript-solution like iScroll.

Is there a way to use **native** pull-to-refresh functionality that reloads the current content of UIWebView?

Comment: So you can't use any of the JavaScript solutions for pull to refresh? 1. [pull-to-refresh](https://github.com/svdgraaf/pull-to-refresh) jQuery plugin 2. [pull to refresh without jquery](http://waynepan.com/2010/07/30/javascript-pull-to-refresh/) 3. [pull to refresh with native scrolling](http://damien.antipa.at/2012/10/16/ios-pull-to-refresh-in-mobile-safari-with-native-scrolling/)

Comment: @SimonMacDonald The last link you posted looked very promising but it doesn't work on Android (just tested on HTC Sensation). Also I need this to work on WP8 :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After weeks of research I found out that there is no solution that works for all my needs. So far it seems like I needed a custom solution for each operating system. This is what I came up with:

- **iOS version < 5**: iScroll
- **iOS version 5+**: http://damien.antipa.at/2012/10/16/ios-pull-to-refresh-in-mobile-safari-with-native-scrolling
- **Android**: iScroll
- **WP8**: Needs an own custom solution

Also it should be noted that WP8 users are not used to "pull to refresh" since it is not a common behaviour on WP. Therefore implementing pull-to-refresh for WP8 should be well thought through.